# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError opencv-contrib

Tags: java, android, opencv

I'm trying to make an application with opencv that is able to recognize a person's face in an image, so I'm trying to use the FacemarkKazemi function of opencv. My problem is that as soon as I switch to class initialization, my application crashes instantly.

You can find the code I'm trying to run here :

https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/master/modules/face/samples/Facemark.java

The application crashes at line 29 here :

```
Facemark fm = Face.createFacemarkKazemi();
```

And i have this error :

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.face.Face.createFacemarkKazemi_0() (tried Java_org_opencv_face_Face_createFacemarkKazemi_10 and Java_org_opencv_face_Face_createFacemarkKazemi_10__)
```

Also, if you know a better way to make FacialMarks, I would be happy to know it.

EDIT : I added this line to my gradle to import opencv contrib, do you think the error could be due to this?

```
implementation 'com.quickbirdstudios:opencv:3.4.4-contrib'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I integrated opencv directly into my project, when I wanted to add opencv-contrib I had to add the gradle to my project (but that never gave me the.so for android) that's why it wasn't able to find the functions, there were no pre-compiled files.
So I downloaded an opencv sdk with opencv contrib and added the.so in the jnilibs folder.